# Remove seconds and AM/PM from Digital clock widget

Tags: android

I want to remove the seconds and AM/PM indication from the digital clock widget but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Are you talking about a widget preinstalled on your phone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is hard-coded in the DigitalClock class, so you can't change it programatically. The only way to change it is to re-implement DigitalClock widget. Yo can get source code from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/DigitalClock.java).

You need to copy this code in your project, rename it like "MyDigitalClock" and use this one as your widget. As you will see in the implementation, there are two variables you should focus on to get what you want:

```
private final static String m12 = "h:mm:ss aa";
private final static String m24 = "k:mm:ss";
```

ss represents seconds and aa represents am/pm.

Answer (score 2):

You could use addTextChangedListener() and then take out the seconds and AM/PM in afterTextChanged(). This example just removes the seconds:

```
DigitalClock dc = (DigitalClock) findViewById(R.id.currentTime);
    dc.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (s.charAt(4) == ':') {
                s.delete(4, 7);
            } else if (s.charAt(5) == ':') {
                s.delete(5, 8);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me little extend and refresh perfect answer from [Erol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1380723/erol).

Actually you need add one file to your project and update xml layout.

Sample could be taken from here: [/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/DigitalClock.java](http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/DigitalClock.java)

Adapted **DigitalClock.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Like AnalogClock, but digital.  Shows seconds.
 *
 * @deprecated It is recommended you use {@link TextClock} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
public class DigitalClock extends TextView {
    // FIXME: implement separate views for hours/minutes/seconds, so
    // proportional fonts don't shake rendering

    Calendar mCalendar;
    @SuppressWarnings("FieldCanBeLocal") // We must keep a reference to this observer
    private FormatChangeObserver mFormatChangeObserver;

    private Runnable mTicker;
    private Handler mHandler;

    private boolean mTickerStopped = false;

    java.text.DateFormat mFormat;

    public DigitalClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initClock();
    }

    public DigitalClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initClock();
    }

    private void initClock() {
        if (mCalendar == null) {
            mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        }

        mFormatChangeObserver = new FormatChangeObserver();
        getContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, mFormatChangeObserver);

        setFormat();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        mTickerStopped = false;
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        /**
         * requests a tick on the next hard-second boundary
         */
        mTicker = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (mTickerStopped) return;
                mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
//                setText(DateFormat.format(mFormat, mCalendar));
                setText(mFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime()));
                invalidate();
                long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                long next = now + (1000 - now % 1000);
                mHandler.postAtTime(mTicker, next);
            }
        };
        mTicker.run();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        mTickerStopped = true;
    }

    private void setFormat() {
//      mFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormatString(getContext());  //<== ORIGINAL
//        mFormat = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext());      //<== Fixed with PM
//        mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        mFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");                  //<== Your variant
    }

    private class FormatChangeObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public FormatChangeObserver() {
            super(new Handler());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            setFormat();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getAccessibilityClassName() {
        //noinspection deprecation
        return DigitalClock.class.getName();
    }
}
```

**layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity" >



    <HERE_YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.DigitalClock
        android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="130dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]