# how to remove seconds from android digital clock

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

```
<DigitalClock  
 android:id="@+id/digitalClock1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
 android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
 android:textSize="20dp"
 android:text="DigitalClock"  
 android:textColor="#646464"/>
```

that is the code for my digital clock and it appears on xml when i run my app like this. 16:39:51. 16 being hours 39 being mins and 51 being seconds. Is there a way i code it in xml or java so when my app is running the clock appears like this format instead 16:39 with 16 being the hours and 39 being the minuites?

Comment: It is not 100% exactly what you are looking for, but could be useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365737/remove-seconds-and-am-pm-from-digital-clock-widget

Answer (score 0):

[`DigitalClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) has been deprecated as of API level 17. It also does not support time formatting.

The replacement, [`TextClock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) supports time formatting via the `setFormat12Hour(CharSequence)` and `setFormat24Hour(CharSequence)` methods.

If you are targeting APIs less than 17, you will have to implement it yourself, either through TextViews or through the method that Zozelfelfo linked in his comment.